# ¿De dónde viene la expresión "dar sopas con honda"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones

Es curioso que yo siempre he pensado que la expresión era "dar sopa con ondas", creo que desde que leí este cómic de Astérix:

[image: Sopaconondas]

Sin embargo, descubro en el diccionario que la expresión es, en realidad:

> [**dar sopas con honda** alguien o algo a otra persona o cosa](https://dle.rae.es/?id=YNaQdnN#3kULeMD)
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Mostrar una superioridad abrumadora sobre ella.

Buscando en Google parece, en todo caso, que la forma "sopa con ondas" tiene más popularidad que la original "sopas con honda". Así pues, ¿cuál es la forma correcta? ¿De dónde viene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desde luego, ni lo de tirar pedazos de pan empapados en un líquido usando un arma ni lo de crear ondulaciones en un caldo parece tener mucho sentido. Sin embargo, todo cobra más sentido si nos fijamos en esta acepción:

> **[sopa de arroyo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=YNaQdnN#3k70tPK)**
>
> 1. f. coloq. desus. Piedra suelta o guijarro.

Esta acepción, hoy en desuso, estaba vigente hace algunos siglos, como atestiguó el *Autoridades* en 1739:

> SOPA DE ARROYO. En estilo festivo llaman à la piedra suelta, ò guijarro; porque en los arroyos suelen estar unas veces en seco, y otras mojadas, conforme crece, ò mengua el agua de ellos.

Se recoge su uso en la segunda parte del Quijote:

> *Asaz de locura sería intentar tal empresa: considere vuesa merced, señor mío, que para sopa de arroyo y tente bonete no hay arma defensiva en el mundo, sino es embutirse y encerrarse en una campana de bronce* [...].

Se entiende pues el origen: aquel que sea capaz de darle con un guijarro y una honda al oponente es el que demostrará mayor pericia.

En todo caso, la expresión parece relativamente reciente en comparación. El primer caso que encuentro es en la hemeroteca de la BNE:

> *Y luego, al final, vendrá la lucha con el traidor, que aunque le dé sopas con honda, tendrá que dejarse vencer, porque si no el director se cabrea.*
>
> **Muchas gracias (Madrid).** 13/10/1928, n.º 244, [página 8](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0003954958&page=8&lang=es).

En la misma hemeroteca es en 1979 cuando aparece el primer caso de la versión "sopa con ondas". Curiosamente, la versión "sopas con onda" aparece en la misma publicación que la citada anteriormente:

> *Con el Extraordinario de Primavera, vamos a dar sopas con onda a la* Vie Parisienne.
>
> **Muchas gracias (Madrid).** 28/3/1925, n.º 61, [página 15](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0003932685&page=15&lang=es).

Por lo cual se ve que la confusión *honda/onda* existió desde el primer momento.

Comment: ¿Entiendo que uno mismo puede responder a la cuestión que plantea? Lo pregunto, porque hace un par de días me riñeron por algo muy similar.

Comment: @karloswitt se puede uno mismo responder a la pregunta, de hecho es recomendable. Si alguna vez has tenido una duda y has encontrado respuesta, puedes quedártela para ti o bien reflejarla aquí. De la segunda forma podrás ayudar a más gente.

Comment: Entonces, si quién pregunta está legitimado, no hay razón para que un usuario le riña, haga bromas crueles, etc., ¿verdad?

Comment: @karloswitt si te preocupa la actitud de algún usuario o tienes alguna duda sobre el funcionamiento del sitio, puedes consultar nuestro sitio Meta o hablar con algún moderador en el chat. De todas formas, cualquier situación en la que se falte al respeto puede ser constitutiva de sanción.

Comment: Pues ya que lo mencionas: te agradecería el enlace al sitio Meta. Y aprovechándome de tu amabilidad: ¿como puedo saber quiénes son los moderadores. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Charlie ha escrito una excelente respuesta, pero quería compartir mis impresiones como nativo de español. Yo esta expresión la utilizo con frecuencia (en su versión «honda»). Mi madre la usaba a menudo, y nunca me planteé qué quería decir. Para mí era gracioso porque con honda puedes tirar solo cosas sólidas y preferiblemente contundentes (una piedra, una pelota de golf, el recuerdo de las vacaciones en Mojácar, un reproductor de música con los mayores éxitos de Manolo Escobar...), pero una sopa es por lo general líquida. Mi lógica infantil, cuando escuchaba a mi madre, era que si eres tan hábil con la honda que eres capaz de lanzar incluso una sopa (!), entonces demostrabas una pericia sin igual y eras superior a cualquier otro iniciado en el arte de los proyectiles, por ducho que sea tu contrincante. Mi línea de pensamiento se vio satisfecha con esta lógica surrealista, más bien digna de una película de José Luis Cuerda. Bastante humorístico (y errado, al parecer), pero en mi infancia no había google para encontrar el significado original (como he hecho hoy). Ahora ya sé que la expresión original era «dar sopas [de arroyo] con honda» ~ «lanzar piedras con honda».

Comment: ¡Me ha encantado está explicación de tu experiencia, que seguro compartimos muchas persona! ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

La expresión "Dar sopas con honda". Sopas (de comer) con honda (de lanzar piedras). Representa una pericia extraordinaria.

Si habéis tenido la suerte de criar a un niño, sabréis lo difícil que es, a veces, que se coma la sopa, con su cucharita, su avioncito y todo, pues hay personas tan hábiles que las dan, pero con honda. En realidad creo que, más que representar las habilidades del que da la sopa, se pone de relieve la gran ventaja que tiene sobre el otro, es decir, que no es que uno sea muy listo, es que el otro puede ser muy tonto.

Comment: Creo que lo que dices representa una de las características de esta expresión: resaltar la superioridad de una persona sobre la otra.